# Plotly - ggplot2 - can't hide repetitive legend text

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, plotly

I'm trying to hide what have become triplicate legend text in plotly using ggplot2. When I render the graph in ggplot, the legend is gone (as I would expect with my code). When I render the graph in plotly, the legend still exists. I don't really want the entire legend gone, just the repetitive legend text. Any thoughts? My code is below with a short example dataset. Thanks!!

```
# Make data
flow = c(5000, 8000, 11000, 5500, 8500, 12000,
     6500, 9500, 12500, 6000, 7000, 11000)
final = c(0.25, 0.55, 0.75, 0.25, 0.55, 0.75,
      0.25, 0.55, 0.75, 0.25, 0.55, 0.75)
rank50c = c("Rank1", "Rank1", "Rank1", "Rank2", "Rank2", "Rank2",
        "Rank3", "Rank3", "Rank3", "Obs", "Obs", "Obs")
plotly.data <- data.frame(flow, final, rank50c)



# Plot it
p <- ggplot(data = plotly.data, aes(x = final, y = flow, colour = rank50c,
                                size = rank50c, linetype = rank50c)) +
  geom_line() +
  xlab("Probability") + ylab("Annual Flow (ML)") + # Set axis labels
  ggtitle("Flow") +  #Set title
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 2, 1, 1.5), "cm")) + 
  scale_size_manual(values = c(2, rep(0.5, 3)), 
                guide = "none") +     #name = "Legend size", 
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("#000000", "#3333FF","#1414ff", "#2727ff"),
                  guide = "none") + #name = "Legend col"
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", rep("dotted", 3)), 
                    guide = "none")  #name = "Legend line",
ggplotly(p)


#p #plotting in ggplot works fine
```

[plotly plot with repetitive legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvjmg.png)

Comment: Thanks @aosmith, that worked to hide the legend. I have edited my question to be more specific. I would like remove the triplicate nature of the legend text (e.g., "Obs, Obs Obs"). I set `guide = "none"` to try and remove the duplicates.

Comment: Now that I realize it's the repetition that's the problem, I find that I can't reproduce the issue.  Are your packages up to date?

Comment: @aosmith, right again. I updated my packages and it plots as expected now. Thanks! Lesson learned, especially with these newer tools.